# Finding item in beautiful soup by text not tag

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

So i'm trying to get the Area for certain locations by scraping it from their wikipedia page. Using Cumbria as an example (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumbria) i can get the info box by;

```
url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumbria'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
value = soup.find('table', {"class": "infobox geography vcard"}) \
            .find('tr', {"class":"mergedrow"}).text
```

however the `infobox geography vcard` has multiple `<tr class='mergerow'>` subsets and within each is a `<th scope='row'>`.

The `<th scope='row'>` that i want is `<th scope="row">Area</th>` and i was wondering if i could get the text from the subset of `<th scope="row">Area</th>` by searching for 'Area' instead of the tags as everything else is ubiquitous under the `infobox geography vcard`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for all `th` with `scope=row` directly. Then iterate over them and see which ones have `Area` as text, and use [`find_next_sibling`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling) to get the next sibling (which will be the `td` with the data you need).

Note that this table has 2 `Area` entries, one for 'Ceremonial county' and one for 'Non-metropolitan county', whatever that means ;).

```
ths = soup.find_all('th', {'scope': 'row'})

for th in ths:
    if th.text == 'Area':
        area = th.find_next_sibling().text
        print(area)

#  6,768 km2 (2,613 sq mi)
#  6,768 km2 (2,613 sq mi)
```

Comment: thanks for that, didn't know about find_next_sibling. Very useful!